# How to revert javascript back to original status

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if the title was clear enough, but I have two forms, one with `uk_inputs` and the other with `international_inputs`. When the uk_input has a value in it, i want to disable all the international inputs. This currently works (with only the first uk_input as im not sure how to for_each over all of them yet), however when the value of the uk_input goes back to "" or 0, I need the international inputs to not be disabled anymore. Is this possible? My attempt is below, thanks

```html
<%= fields.input :line_1, input_html: {class: "uk_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :line_2, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :line_3, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :town, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :county, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :postcode, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
```

```html
<%= fields.input :line_1, input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :line_2, input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :line_3, input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :town, label: "City / Region", input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :postcode, label: "Postcode / ZIP Code", input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
```

**Javascript**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var uk_input = document.querySelector(".uk_input");
  uk_input.onchange = function() {
    if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
      international_input = document.querySelectorAll(".international_input")
      international_input.forEach(function(international) {
        international.disabled = true
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var uk_input = document.querySelector(".uk_input");
uk_input.onchange = function () {
  international_input =  document.querySelectorAll(".international_input")
  international_input.forEach(function(international) {
    international.disabled = !uk_input.value
  });
}
```

What this does is to loop through the inputs every time `uk_input` is changed and to disable/enable them based on if the `uk_input` had or doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the simple and short answer is: set the `disable` prop to the true of false depends on the `uk_input`'s value.

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var uk_input = document.querySelector(".uk_input");
  uk_input.onchange = function() {
    const shouldDisable = this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0;
    international_input = document.querySelectorAll(".international_input")
    international_input.forEach(function(international) {
      international.disabled = shouldDisable;
    })
  }
});
```

If you're already using jQuery, you can use its api:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // bind **all** the inputs change
  $('.uk_input').change(function() {
    // check if any of them has value
    const anyInputHasValue = $('.uk_input').filter((index, item) => !!item.value).length;
    // loop through all the international inputs
    $(".international_input").each(function () {
      // set it prop "disabled" to true if any of the uk inputs has value and vice versa
      $(this).prop('disabled', anyInputHasValue);
    });
  }
});
```